# Is there a way to disable device encryption on nokia 6.1?

Tags: rooting, root-access

My phone is encrypted out of the box, I have tried formatting it the normal way, via settings, but afterwards, it is still encrypted.

Is there a way to remove the device encryption? I need to enable OEM unlock, and that cannot work when the device is still encrypted.

Device: Nokia 6.1

OS: Android 10

Android security patch level: 1st April, 2021

Comment: Where did you got the info that an encrypted device can not be unlocked? If that would be true all phones release in the last ~4 years could not be unlocked. Have you tried to enable OEM unlock in developer settings and then boot to fastboot?

Comment: The `enable OEM` option is there but it is deactivated. How can I be able to unlock it?

Comment: This page contains a nice list why oem unlock may be grayed out: https://nerdschalk.com/how-to-fix-oem-unlock-greyed-out-or-oem-unlock-disabled-problem/

Comment: in order to disable encryption one must unlock bootloader first. check for Björn Kerler's tools

Comment: https://github.com/bkerler/edl/blob/master/README.md#for-generic-unlocking